# How do I multiply permutations? From left or from right?

Tags: permutations, convention

How do I multiply permutations? From left or from right? My understanding is that I go from right to left as the permutation closest to the element acts first:

1. I assume it's $(12)(13)(14)=(1432)$
2. Or is it really $(12)(13)(14)=(1234)$?

Comment: You can do it either way as long as you do it the same way all the time. Different books/classes make different decisions at the start of the exposition, then stick with it. I personally prefer (2).

Comment: But doesn't that somehow conflict with $(f\circ g)(z)=f(g(z))$?

Comment: @Buh Some people also read function composition from left to right.

Comment: @Buh Yes it conflicts with that interpretation, but when I'm working in the symmetric group I think of it more abstractly as products of cycles with left to right multiplication. If I need to interpret the permutations as functions then they are acting on the other side of their arguments. Herstein's algebra text writes function applications as $(x)f$ precisely so that composition reads left to right. I don't comfortably go that far.

Comment: I see. Very interesting! Thank you for this answer.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305322/104041)

Answer (score 0):

The order of composition of permutations is a matter of convention. Both directions are in use.

However, since the argument of a function is traditionally on the right (and a permutation is a function on its defining set), it is more common to find the right-to-left convention.

Examples of when the left-to-right convention is in use are  semigroup theory and formal languages.